# Find the convergence radius of series

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers

I need to find the convergence radius of the following series:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \cos in \times z^n$$
Since
$$\cos in = \cosh n = {\frac{e^{in} + e^{-in}}{2}}$$
therefore, using D'Alembert's property I find the limit as
$$\lim {\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}} = {\frac{e^{i(n+1)} + e^{-i(n+1)}}{2}} \times z^n \times z \times {\frac{2}{(e^{in} + e^{-in})z^n}} = \lim z \times {\frac{e^{i(n+1)} + e^{-i(n+1)}}{e^{in} + e^{-in}}} = z$$
Therefore the radius should be 1. But the answer on the book is ${\frac{1}{e}}$.
What's wrong with my solution?

Comment: Are you sure this is the definition of $\cosh n$ you wrote? Looks like $\cos n$...

Comment: isn't it the same as $\cos n$, only with $i$s added to the exponentiation of $e$?

Comment: (also, even assuming it's correct, not clear how you compute your last limit. The ratio does not tend to $1$, whether you look at what you wrote or the correct one.)

Comment: @OP: $$\cos x = \frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$$ and $$\cosh x = \frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2}$$ you picked the wrong one.

Comment: actually by Moivre's relationship $\cos(\theta)=\frac{e^{i\theta}+e{-i\theta}}2$

Comment: So it should be $${\frac{e^n + e^{-n}}{2}}$$?

Comment: Further, the main issue you have is that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{e^{n+1}+e^{-(n+1)}}{e^{n}+e^{-n}} = e$$ (not $1$); and, with your current mistake, you have also an error anyway, as $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{e^{i(n+1)}+e^{-i(n+1)}}{e^{in}+e^{-in}}$$ does not even exist.

Comment: @user3132457 Yes, that's what I'm saying.

Comment: Okay, but I still don't get how the limit is $e$

Comment: See my answer, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two errors here. The first is that
$$
\cosh n = \frac{e^n + e^{-n}}{2}
$$
not what you wrote *(which is $\cos n$. To remember: $\cosh$ is unbounded on $\mathbb{R}$, so you have "true" exponentials, while $\cos$ is bounded, so you have $e^{i x}$ which is bounded)*. So you need to compute 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{e^{n+1}+e^{-(n+1)}}{e^{n}+e^{-n}} \tag{1}$$ and not $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{e^{i(n+1)}+e^{-i(n+1)}}{e^{in}+e^{-in}}$ (where you also made a mistake, the second: this limit does *not* exist, anyway!).

So let's compute (1):
$$
\frac{e^{n+1}+e^{-(n+1)}}{e^{n}+e^{-n}}
= \frac{e^n(e+e^{-(2n+1)})}{e^n(1+e^{-2n})} = 
= \frac{e+e^{-(2n+1)}}{1+e^{-2n}} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \frac{e+0}{1+0} = e\,.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = z\cdot e \tag{2}
$$
which explains why the radius is $\frac{1}{e}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

We can use https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Proof_of_convergence

far more easily,so that we  need $$|ez|<1$$ and $$\left|\dfrac ze\right|<1$$

Comment: The OP *is* using the ratio test.

Comment: @ClementC, Please find updated answer